# using a function inside a discriminated union

Tags: f#

I  would like to do some unit tests on a function that accepts a DU and returns another :

```
type Commands = 
  | Schedule of string
  | Abandon of string

type Events =
  | Scheduled of string
  | Abandonned of string
```

the function is the following :

```
let exec state = function
    | Schedule (cmd) -> Choice1Of2( Scheduled("yes")) 
    | Abandon(cmd)  -> Choice1Of2( Abandonned ("no"))
```

My tests are as follows :

```
let result:Choice<Events,string> = exec "initial state" <| Schedule("myCommand");;
```

result has the following type `Choice<Events,string>`, I would have loved to get some quick function in order to use them like this :

```
assertEvent Scheduled (fun e -> Assert.Equal("should produce GameScheduled Event",gameScheduled, e)) result
```

But to do that I would have the following home made assert function :

```
let assertEvent<'TEvent> f g result =
    match result  with
        | Choice1Of2(e) -> 
            match e with 
            | f(evt) ->  g(evt)
            | _ -> Assert.None("event not recognised",Some(e)) 
        | Choice2Of2(reason) -> Assert.None("reason",Some(reason))
```

I was expecting the function f to allow  pattern matching on the fly but it does not. Instead I have the following error :

```
The pattern disciminator 'f' is not defined
```

Am I doing somthing wrong somewhere ? my fsharp skills are not that high...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal function like `f` can't be used as a pattern discriminator, but you *can* pass [Active Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248) around as arguments:

```
let assertEvent<'TEvent> (|F|_|) g result =
    match result  with
        | Choice1Of2(e) -> 
            match e with 
            | F(evt) ->  g(evt)
            | _ -> Assert.None("event not recognised",Some(e)) 
        | Choice2Of2(reason) -> Assert.None("reason",Some(reason))
```

This does, however, require you to also pass an Active Pattern as an argument, which is a bit cumbersome:

```
assertEvent
    (function Scheduled(x) -> Some x | _ -> None)
    (fun e -> Assert.Equal("should produce GameScheduled Event",gameScheduled, e))
    result
```

---

This isn't the way I'd approach the problem, though. What I'd prefer is to write a boolean expression that attempts to pull out and compare the values that I want to verify.

For starters, you could create a little generic helper function to pull out one of the choices from `Choice<'a, 'b>`:

```
let toOption1 = function Choice1Of2 x -> Some x | _ -> None
```

This function has the type `Choice<'a,'b> -> 'a option`. (I'll leave it as an exercise to define an equivalent `toOption2` function.)

Now you can define a boolean expression that pulls out the data if it's there, and compares it with an expected value:

```
result
|> toOption1
|> Option.map (function Scheduled x -> x | _ -> "")
|> Option.exists ((=) expected)
```

This is a boolean expression, so you can use [Unquote](http://www.swensensoftware.com/unquote) to turn it into an assertion. This is similar to [this approach that I've previously described](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/21/composed-assertions-with-unquote).

Comment: thx for your answer, I was expecting to refactor my assertions to make them easier to write and read, so that does not do the job, but will accept it as answer if nothing better comes. thx again.

Comment: @CygnusX-1 Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See my updated answer.